# Change the color of the taskbar

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-10, taskbar

I have a client-server windows form application and I need to make a border at the corners of the screen in order to understand visually to which server I am connected. I searched a lot but found nothing, so i thought to change the color of the [taskbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h7bRq.jpg) every time the server is the target of the client.
But I don't know how to get the control of the taskbar from the visual studio(c#).
Any idea?

I tried to use :

```
[DllImport("dwmapi.dll", PreserveSig = false)]
```

Comment: Not sure about changing color of whole taskbar area, but you can try to inform user with taskbar functions. Look at this article on taskbar API
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd942846.aspx

Answer (score 1):

To change the color of the whole taskbar (I'm assuming you're talking windows 7 or later), you have to change the windows visual theme color, such as can be done through **Control Panel->Personalization->Color and Appearance.**

I don't think the color of the task bar has any correlation with an application, and that it is a system-wide setting (or more correctly, user-wide).

I believe that's what you're after, how to change the windows color theme/scheme.

To this end, I think you want to use the WIN32API call [SetSystemVisualStyle](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/uxtheme.SetSystemVisualStyle) (uxtheme.dll)

It's possible you set the system theme color but it could be appear real light so as to make it difficult to tell it changed at all. This may happen if the windows style is "Aero Glass" instead of "Aero Basic". The WIN32API call to change THAT is discussed in the second answer to this stackoverflow question: [How to change windows color scheme using c#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4700308/how-to-change-windows-color-scheme-using-c)

For older versions of windows, (I think) or if the above API calls isn't working for you, you might try the WIN32API call: [SetWindowTheme](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/uxtheme.SetWindowTheme) (uxtheme.dll)

I noticed in your question, you made reference to dwmapi.dll. Looking at [pinvoke.net](http://www.pinvoke.net),  I notice some relevant WIN32API calls, namely
[DwmSetColorizationParameters](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/dwmapi.DwmSetColorizationParameters) (dwmapi.dll) which sounds like it can indeed change a single window's Aero theme color after all, as well as things like transparency of the window. However, from what I read, this may not be supported in the newer/ist version of windows, but it is purported to create a smooth transition from one color to the other. For further information, please see this codeproject here: [Changing Windows Aero Color](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/610909/Changing-Windows-Aero-Color)

Let me know if this works out for you, I would be curious to hear if this has solved your problem or not.

Answer (score 0):

As seen in [multiple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14663515/changing-taskbar-button-color-on-windows#14664113) [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34696332/change-the-taskbar-color-of-windows-10/34722807), you can not change the taskbar color. You could, however, change your application icon based on your context (an icon per server, perhaps)

Comment: Yes you can, loads of windows programs do it. Orange flashes, orange static, red, yellow, green progress, green static.... I have seen a load of colors on taskbar buttons. If only I would find how.